# ContentTools - How to keep data- attributes during mount/unmount

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I'm using ContentTools editor in a project. http://getcontenttools.com/ 
I have img tags with data-foo attributes. I want these attributes to be passed on/kept during the mount/unmount process. Currently they are removed completely.

Here is my example img tag:

```
 <img data-foo="SAVEME" class="align-right" height="300" src="/images/pages/demo/click-and-hold-to-drag.png" width="300" >
```

After initializing ContentTools:

```
<div class="align-right ce-element ce-element--type-image" style="background-image:url('/images/pages/demo/click-and-hold-to-drag.png');width:300px;height:300px;" data-ce-size="w 300 × h 300"></div>
```

As you can see the 'data-foo="SAVEME"' is now removed. 
Is there a way to save data- attributes? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to patch the images `mount` method so that it applies data attributes like so:

```
var _super = ContentEdit.Image.prototype.mount;

ContentEdit.Image.prototype.mount = function() {
    _super.call(this);
    for (var attrName in this._attributes) {
        if (attrName.startsWith('data-')) {
            this._domElement.setAttribute(attrName, this._attributes[attrName]);
        }
    }
};
```